# Symfony 3, email resetting FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, email, fosuserbundle

During the Resetting of the password, an email is sent with a token to activate the procedure. Out, the email does not leave. I loocked in config.yml, service[...], and other files indicated in the docs and other media. Without progress.

If I understood correctly, this is played in config.yml, so here is what I currently have in it. And I use Swiftmailer.

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: App\AdminBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    from_email:
        address: "XXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"
        sender_name: "XXXXX"
    registration:
        form:
            type: App\AdminBundle\Form\RegistrationType
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template: FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
    resetting:
        email:
            template: FOSUserBundle:Resetting:email.txt.twig
```

Thanks for your help.

After request of knetsi, my prod.log of yesterday

```
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] request.INFO: Matched route "app_support_theme". {"route":"app_support_theme","route_parameters":{"_controller":"App\\SupportBundle\\Controller\\SupportController::sommaireAction","id":"1","_route":"app_support_theme"},"request_uri":"http://www.annaangeliqueporte.fr/app.php/support/summary/1","method":"GET"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] security.DEBUG: Read existing security token from the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username_1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical_2, t0.email AS email_3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical_4, t0.enabled AS enabled_5, t0.salt AS salt_6, t0.password AS password_7, t0.last_login AS last_login_8, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token_9, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at_10, t0.roles AS roles_11, t0.id AS id_12, t0.motdepasse AS motdepasse_13 FROM user t0 WHERE t0.id = ? LIMIT 1 [1] []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] security.DEBUG: User was reloaded from a user provider. {"username":"anna","provider":"FOS\\UserBundle\\Security\\UserProvider"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\DebugHandlersListener::configure"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\EventListener\\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\FirewallListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\ControllerListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\SecurityListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\TemplateListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.title AS title_2, t0.created AS created_3, t0.modified AS modified_4, t0.deleted AS deleted_5 FROM theme t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [1] []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT s0_.id AS id_0, s0_.title AS title_1, s0_.text AS text_2, s0_.publish AS publish_3, s0_.created AS created_4, s0_.modified AS modified_5, s0_.deleted AS deleted_6, c1_.id AS id_7, c1_.chapitre AS chapitre_8, c1_.title AS title_9, c1_.created AS created_10, c1_.modified AS modified_11, c1_.deleted AS deleted_12, s0_.theme_id AS theme_id_13, s0_.chapitre_id AS chapitre_id_14 FROM support s0_ INNER JOIN chapitre c1_ ON s0_.chapitre_id = c1_.id WHERE s0_.theme_id = 1 AND s0_.publish = 1 AND s0_.deleted IS NULL [] []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice: Undefined offset: 0" at /var/www/html/PFolio/src/App/SupportBundle/Controller/SupportController.php line 20 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Notice: Undefined offset: 0 at /var/www/html/PFolio/src/App/SupportBundle/Controller/SupportController.php:20)"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\DebugHandlersListener::configure"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\EventListener\\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener::onKernelRequest". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\FirewallListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\ControllerListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\SecurityListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController". {"event":"kernel.controller","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\TemplateListener::onKernelController"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\RememberMe\\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\ContextListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\FirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". {"event":"kernel.exception","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\Firewall\\ExceptionListener::onKernelException"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onException". {"event":"kernel.exception","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SwiftmailerBundle\\EventListener\\EmailSenderListener::onException"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException". {"event":"kernel.exception","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ExceptionListener::onKernelException"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.exception". {"event":"kernel.exception","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ExceptionListener::onKernelException"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] security.DEBUG: Stored the security token in the session. {"key":"_security_main"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Http\\RememberMe\\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Sensio\\Bundle\\FrameworkExtraBundle\\EventListener\\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SaveSessionListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse". {"event":"kernel.response","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\TranslatorListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\FirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest". {"event":"kernel.finish_request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SecurityBundle\\EventListener\\FirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest"} []
[2018-01-08 17:14:31] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". {"event":"kernel.terminate","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\SwiftmailerBundle\\EventListener\\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate"} []
```

Comment: from which enviroment are you trying to send the email, production,development,test? If it is from the development make sure that you have not disabled the mail transfer, **app/config/config_dev.yml** `disable_delivery` . Also if you are in development enviroment you could use the symfony profiler to see if there is any error or if any e-mail was sent

Comment: I am in production environment. My dev environment does not allow sending mail. My classic mails go well. Only those of FOSUserBundle do not want.

Comment: your configuration looks right, can you post your logs to see if there is a hint there, `var/logs/prod.log`

Comment: Update of my post

Comment: Can you please also post your security access_control settings, `app/config/security.yml`. I can see from your logs that there is an Exception thrown from firewall and propagating to Swiftmailer. Is your path for resetting available to anonymous users? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html#step-4-configure-your-application-s-security-yml

Comment: The problem is solved and didn't come from the code. I used my gmail account to test my mailings and the ip of my server was blocked by security. It's now resolved. Thank you :)